# Python - renaming files twice with os

Tags: python, regex, python-os

I am currently working on a script to take raw text files, place them in correct year folders based on a version number system, and rename them so that our devs can integrate them into our product easily.

The file in question is called APR30CaseRVU-1Day.txt. 
I need this to be in the form refAPRCaseRVU-1Day.txt.

Append ref, remove 30, keep 1Day.

The script works fine for the other files that do not have this extra "1Day". I'm a beginner so I'm sure my workflow is shit but my idea was to use os.rename twice. Once to remove the characters, and then split on the hyphen to add the "1" back in to the filename, but when I print the filename after the first os.rename it still has 30 and 1.

Anyone have any tips to do this more effectively?

```
folder = r"C:\Users\xx\Desktop\Python Final Project\Raw"

import os
import re
import shutil
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(folder):
for filename in filenames:
    srcpath = os.path.join(root, filename)
    #split the filename so that we can rename accordingly below, filename_split[0] = filename, filename_split[1] = file ext
    filename_split = os.path.splitext(filename)
    name = filename_split[0]
    ext = filename_split[1]
    newfolder = ''
    destpath = os.path.join(newfolder, "ref" + re.sub(r'\d', '', filename_split[0]) + filename_split[1])
    #first step: remove AP files entirely from directory
    if filename.startswith("AP27"):
        os.remove(os.path.join(folder, filename))
    #the rest include a version number that must be routed to the correct year folder directory created above
    elif filename.__contains__("30") and filename.__contains__("Day"):
        newfolder = r"C:\Users\xx\Desktop\Python Final Project\Raw\2013"
        os.rename(os.path.join(root, filename),
                  os.path.join(newfolder, "ref" + re.sub(r'\d', '', filename_split[0]) + filename_split[1]))
        print(filename)
        day_name = re.split(r'[\s-]+', filename)
        print(day_name)
        first_name = day_name[0]
        last_name = day_name[1]
        os.rename(os.path.join(newfolder, filename),
                      os.path.join(newfolder, "ref" + first_name + '1' + last_name))
```

Comment: You aren't expecting `os.rename()` to modify the `filename` variable, correct?  If you are, that would be a problem.

Comment: no, i do not want to modify the filename variable.

Comment: Ok, I didn't think so, but `print the filename` in the question and `print(filename)` in the code had me worried.  Based on your code...it tentatively looks like you want: find `(.*)30(.*Day.*)` replace with `ref$1$2` (where $1 and $2 are the contents of parentheses in find.  https://regex101.com/r/0vJduG/1/  I'd give you an actual answer, but my python is crap, and i'm not 100% clear on your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I just got it working by adding {2} to '\d' which meant it looked for 2 consecutive numbers, and replaced those, but kept the 1 in 1Day.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this myself:

```
                os.rename(os.path.join(root, filename),
                      os.path.join(newfolder, "ref" + re.sub(r'\d{2}', '', name) + ext))
```

Adding the {2} made it look for 2 consecutive numbers, and left the 1 alone.

Thanks!